# Query IP2Location LITE binary databases using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, binary

I would like to use Haskell to query the IP2Location LITE binary databases from [here](http://lite.ip2location.com/databases). So I am wondering if there are any existing modules or codes to read the databases?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ip2location, but there is geoip2 native module that works with Geoip2 database. Depending on what you want to use it for it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example code from [Github](https://github.com/ip2location/ip2location-haskell):

```
import IP2Location

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myfile = "IPV6-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ZIPCODE-TIMEZONE-ISP-DOMAIN-NETSPEED-AREACODE-WEATHER-MOBILE-ELEVATION-USAGETYPE.BIN"
    meta <- doInit myfile
    result <- doQuery myfile meta "8.8.8.8"
    putStrLn $ "country_short: " ++ (show (country_short result))
    putStrLn $ "country_long: " ++ (show (country_long result))
    putStrLn $ "region: " ++ (show (region result))
    putStrLn $ "city: " ++ (show (city result))
    putStrLn $ "isp: " ++ (show (isp result))
    putStrLn $ "latitude: " ++ (show (latitude result))
    putStrLn $ "longitude: " ++ (show (longitude result))
    putStrLn $ "domain: " ++ (show (domain result))
    putStrLn $ "zipcode: " ++ (show (zipcode result))
    putStrLn $ "timezone: " ++ (show (timezone result))
    putStrLn $ "netspeed: " ++ (show (netspeed result))
    putStrLn $ "iddcode: " ++ (show (iddcode result))
    putStrLn $ "areacode: " ++ (show (areacode result))
    putStrLn $ "weatherstationcode: " ++ (show (weatherstationcode result))
    putStrLn $ "weatherstationname: " ++ (show (weatherstationname result))
    putStrLn $ "mcc: " ++ (show (mcc result))
    putStrLn $ "mnc: " ++ (show (mnc result))
    putStrLn $ "mobilebrand: " ++ (show (mobilebrand result))
    putStrLn $ "elevation: " ++ (show (elevation result))
    putStrLn $ "usagetype: " ++ (show (usagetype result))
```

You'll need to install the IP2Location package using cabal:

```
cabal install IP2Location
```

Hackage page: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ip2location-8.0.4/docs/IP2Location.html